# Making vector geometries "Kiss" in QGIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, topology, simplify

I am working with vector geometries that I recently simplified using the native:simplifygeometries method in the processing toolbox. I am pleased with the simplification but I want to "fill" the gaps in between the geometries so there is no empty space.

How do I make all of the geometries kiss each other?

I don't care which geometry the extra space is allocated to but it cannot itself be a new geometry.
Perhaps there is a better simplification method to use that doesn't lead to this problem, but I need the features to be highly simplified.

[image: Geometries that dont quite fill all the space]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better method to simplify is using the GRASS tool v.generalize from `Menu Processing / Toolbox`. It keeps topology intact, thus no need to fill sliver polygons.

I' m not sure if you only have gaps - if the polygons also overlap, you must run at least two tools. So probably starting to create simplified and topologically correct geometries (no gaps, no overlaps) from scratch is the better option as it involves only one tool.

See the screenshot where I use the tool with a tolerance value of 2 km (2000 [m]) - it's just one single parameter I have to set and the tool runs for a few seconds (be sure to have a layer in a projected CRS):

[image: GRASS GIS v.generalize input parameter settings]

Output looks like:

[image: GRASS GIS v.generalize output]