# Simplify, while keeping the neighboring edges

Tags: qgis

When using simplify on vectors of Polygons in QGIS we discover that the polygons lose their edges with their neighbours.
Either with the new edges leading to overlapping, or  the edges lose their connection.
[image]
Is there an implementation of simplify, that that does not change the neighbourhood relationship? So when vertices on a edge is changed, moved, removed, that this is done for all polygons, that share the current edge?

Comment: What GIS software were you using when you got that undesirable result from simplify?  Please only ask about one alternative software per question and describe what you’ve tried/researched with that particular software.

Comment: I would use the v.generalize tool in QGIS's GRASS section.  You can try different tolerances and methods but GRASS tools are topological.  If you are unsure your polygons are in fact topologically correct lacking any gaps and overlaps, you might run the v.clean tool first followed by the delete duplicate geometries QGIS tool, and then run v.generalize.

Comment: Convert to lines, simplify, construct polygons.

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383191/88814

Comment: @FelixIP I don't see how this solves the problem of not preserving topology

Comment: @Babel it depends how you convert to lines. There are tools at least in arcgis, that result in a single line on shared boundaries of 2 polygons.