# Automatically Locating Missing Vertices then creating on Adjacent Polygon or Polyline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vertices

I have 2 polygons. After the simplification and alignment using Snap Geometries to Layer tool, I want to have same vertices on adjacent polygons or polylines.
Because of running the required tool, the vertices get lost or increased.

Is there any way to locate or monitor the vertices automatically on adjacent polygons and producing the missing on either sides?

The photos are given below[image: The left downsided vertex is missing on other image[1]]

[image]

Comment: Not sure exactly about your workflow/goal. However, when genalizing, you can keep topology intact with GRASS tool v.generalize, see: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383191/88814

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But for my case its not working. I have number of polygons and these polygons share boundaries with gaps and overlaps. I am doing simplification with Douglas distance tool followed by aligning the simplified polygons using Snap Geometries to Layer tool. Still the vertices are missing as shown in the pictures above. Is there any tool in qgis or could we do it with pycode?

Comment: I dont understand. The only vertice missing from the top polygon is the rightmost one in the upper screenshot?

Comment: yes. because that one is only present in one layer.